# How to pass an array of variable names to list()

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass an array of variable names to be assigned to the `list()` function, and I'm wondering if it's even possible. My intention is for `list($variables)` to parse `$values`.

```
$variables = array("$var1","$var2","$var3");
$values = array('Value1','Value2','Value3');

//Can I simply pass an array of variable names to be assigned here
list($values) = explode("&", $values);
```

To clarify, my intention is to have PHP execute this:

```
list($var1, $var2, $var3) = explode("&", $values);
```

Comment: what error you have or what part of code is not working

Comment: I simply want to execute the last line of code, by passing an array of the the variable names to list(). There is no part of the code that is working. I don't think it's possible to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to do a little trickery, but with `array_combine` and `extract` you could achieve the same effect:

```
$keys = array("var1","var2","var3");
$values = array('Value1','Value2','Value3');
extract(array_combine($keys, $values));
echo $var1; //"Value1"
```

Comment: You are literally the only person who understood the question. Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: you could also use something like call_user_func_array, but i think this way is more understandable honestly
EDIT: Here's the man page for that
http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$info = array('coffee', 'brown', 'caffeine');

// Listing all the variables
list($drink, $color, $power) = $info;
echo "$drink is $color and $power makes it special.\n";

// Listing some of them
list($drink, , $power) = $info;
echo "$drink has $power.\n";

// Or let's skip to only the third one
list( , , $power) = $info;
echo "I need $power!\n";

// list() doesn't work with strings
list($bar) = "abcde";
var_dump($bar); // NULL
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

Answer (score 0):

`list` is used to assign a list of variables in one operation. This is the sytax:

```
$string = 'VarA, VarB, VarC';
list($varA, $varB, $varC) = explode(',', $string);
```

When u use variables you can need to keep the quotes away so the second is the right one.

```
$array = ($var1, $var2, $var3);
```

You dont need to use `explode` anymore cause you already have an array. `explode` creates an array. In your example it would be:

```
$array = array($var1, $var2, $var3);
list($varA, $varB, $varC) = $array;
```

Note that i changed the array syntax. You forgot the `array` keyword.

Comment: My intention is to pass an array of the variable names to be assigned.

Comment: If you want to pass an Array of variable names you can use 
`$array = array('var1', 'var2', 'var3');
list($varA, $varB, $varC) = $array;` but i don't see the purpose of this..

Comment: Say you have 50 variable names you want to assign from an API response, declaring 50 variable names in the list() function does not seem efficient. Much easier to use arrays that you can pass to a function on call.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want to explode the response variable and assign each value to the corresponding variable.

You can achieve it this way instead of using list:

```
$varnames = array('var1','var2','var3');
$varvals  = explode('&',$response);
foreach($varnames as $k => $v){
    $$v = $varvals[$k];
}
```

This way $var1 will have the first value in response, $var2 the second, and so on.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that. Why you don't use the second your variant?

Comment: I didn't downvote but they did because the second variant `list($var1, $var2, $var3) = explode("&", $response);` is also incorrect.

Comment: Okay. I just have said about the «list()» struct syntax.